# Sharing Firebase Storage Images using Facebook SDK (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs, facebook-javascript-sdk, firebase-storage

I am using Firebase to store user images. I want to add the ability for the user to share these photos on Facebook. I created a project on Facebook Developers. I am currently using React so below is a watered down version of my component.

```
class Share extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            //SDK loaded, initialize it
            FB.init({
                appId      : 'app-id',
                xfbml      : true,
                version    : 'v2.6'
            });
            //JS SDK initialized, now you can use it
            FB.XFBML.parse();
        };

        //load the JavaScript SDK
        (function(d, s, id){
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <a onClick={() => {
                FB.ui({
                    method: 'share',
                    display: 'popup',
                    href: imageData.image_url
                })
            }}>Share</a>
        )
    }
}

/*
    imageData.image_url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/zoostagram-c0ec2.appspot.com/o/journey%2FTbewuTE9MDZaBByadZUz9kXjtK93%2F-LAucp-cHpPUWnMmn_GV%2F174915781175375011-1618340686-1759905821-1592844446-1892410559-711095936445312870.jpg?alt=media&token=5a37d0d5-2917-4783-ab4c-2dbd94734320"
*/
```

The Facebook share popup does open, so I am assuming that the `FB.init()` function worked fine. However, I am getting an error on the popup which says: "**Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.**"

I have tried to add `firebasestorage.googleapis.com` to my app domains but it doesn't get saved because it isn't my site URL. Other notes, I am using 'create-react-app' so still developing in localhost. I also tried to run `encodeURI(url)` & `encodeURIComponent(url)`, neither of which worked.

Comment: share urls of your website, including the image as og:image instead

Comment: The page currently lists images that were taken by the user, I want the ability to share individual images and not the page itself.